# Leak memory tool cannot detect leak when assign property, so, is leak mem or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I programing iOS application. I have class **Car** and class **Wheel**. Class Car has one property Wheel (only in this example, in real, Car have more than one wheel).

In class Car:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Wheel * wheel; //because it has retain, so I delete wheel in dealloc function.
```

When I has a Car object, I init wheel.

```
Car* car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.wheel = [[Wheel alloc] init];
```

I think that code make a leak memory, but Leak detector tool in Instrument tools in XCode not detect it. So, what is happening ? May be I wrong ?

Thank for your helping.

Comment: Is this compiled with ARC enabled?  Also, what does your `dealloc` look like?

Comment: @Hyperbole - good question about the ARC, though wouldn't a dealloc call or a release call throw an error with it enabled?

Comment: @XenElement Sure, but he doesn't say he's calling `release`, he says he deletes it, which could be interpreted as `self.wheel = nil;` or `_wheel = nil;`, which are not a compiler errors under ARC.

Comment: I disable ARC. This is code of my friend and I know it has a memory leak, but I don't know why Leak Detector of Instrument tool not detect this error. My dealloc is : `if(wheel) [wheel release]; wheel = nil;`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared your `wheel` property to retain an object given to it, send a `autorelease` message to your `Wheel` object:

```
Car* car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.wheel = [[[Wheel alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: My thinking like yours, but I'm not sure about it. With you and other people answer, I can sure about it. Thank you.

Comment: @huync This is the answer you want.  Disabling ARC is short-sighted.  Read [the memory management guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).